# AngularJS $http.get() always returns error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why does the code below runs the error callback with no status? Web Developer in Firefox reports status code 200.

Is there any way to debug this?

```
<meta charset="utf8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function RoomListCtrl($scope, $http) {

        $scope.getRooms = function() {

                $http({method: 'GET', url: 'http://code.angularjs.org'}).

                success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // this callback will be called asynchronously
                // when the response is available
                    alert('succes');
                }).

                error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
                    alert('error');
                });
        }

        $scope.submit = function() {

            this.getRooms();
        }

    }

</script>
```

```
<body ng-controller="RoomListCtrl"><form ng-submit="submit()">
    <input type="text" value="" ng-model="search" name="search" >
</form></body>
```

Comment: Is that the actual code you're running? Sounds like you're running into [cross-domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) issues, where the actual request is being blocked (so no status either).

Comment: Yes, this is actual code. I am running this code as local file in Firefox. Could that cause the issue?

Comment: Even if you would run it through an HTTP server, it would generate an error because you can't generally perform cross-domain AJAX requests (unless the remote server handling the request has [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) enabled, but it doesn't look like `code.angularjs.org` has).

Answer (score 1):

As @robertklep points out above, you can't make ajax request to another domain unless that domain explicitly allows it. See the [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/) link he provided. One workaround to this (assuming you can't control the CORS policy for the server you're requesting data from) is to use a [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) request if the server supports that.